# Approval bypass

Tags: community, approval-process

I want to set the below condition in my approval process.

1) Billing is a picklist (Bill/Non Bill)

Is there a way to bypass the approval process if the timecard is non-bill and has  a case number and not a contract number.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=approvals_creating_approval_steps.htm&siteLang=en_US). You have the option to skip a step if a filter criteria or the entered formula will evaluate to true.

Comment: Hi Mihai, unable to open the above doc.

Comment: Check to see if you don't have any proxy or firewall settings that prevent you to access the link. https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=approvals_creating_approval_steps.htm&siteLang=en_US This is the full link, I can access it with no problem